# Wizard's Fury grants a second attack per turn?

Tags: dnd-4e, powers, attack

I was wondering if it was possible to chain the effect of Wizard's Fury's power on following turns (after the turn I activate it) with other attack spells for a secondary attack each turn, seeing as how the use of Magic Missile through Wizard's Fury counts as a Minor Action.

For example, I cast Wizard's Fury on my opening turn, then on my next turn, I use a power like Acid Arrow as my standard action, then as part of the same turn, use Magic Missile by way of Wizard's Fury's ongoing effect as a Minor Action.

In two related questions, can I use the effect of Wizard's Fury the same turn I cast it to get off an attack on the same turn, and If I cast Magic Missile normally, can I use Wizard's Fury's ongoing effect to cast a second MM during the same turn?

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 9):

### Yes on both questions.

"Casting" [Wizards' Fury](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/power.aspx?id=7429)<sup>DDI</sup> is a minor action. Once cast (that means: since the same round you activated Wizard's Fury), you can use a minor action to cast Magic Missile.

This quick cast is limited to once per turn, but you can also spend a standard action and cast Magic Missile normally.

---

So, these chain of actions is perfectly legal.

**Round 1**
Minor action: Wizard's Fury.
Minor action: Magic Missile (from WF).
Standard action: Freezing Cloud.

**Round 2**
Minor action: Magic Missile (from WF).
Standard action: Magic Missile (normal At-Will attack).
Minor action: Sustain the Freezing Cloud.

Comment: Devastating chain of powers, but note lack of movement though :-). Generally Wizards Fury sits alongside similar Daily powers that are intended to give you an encounter-long upgrade. It is intended to be used in this way, and is in no way excessive to do so when compared to equivalent powers.

Comment: Thanks again, now all I need is another Level and a half to get Melf's Minute Meteors for triple-attack goodness (At least I think you can use both with regular Standard Action attack powers). :)

Comment: Yes, you can. Being both the meteor and the magic missile provided by Wizard's Fury minor actions to be launched. ^_^